# A lottery ticket is made of 5 numbers, how many have the number 2 only twice?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A lottery ticket is made of 5 numbers, from 0 to 9. The number 00000 is
>   not included.
>
> How many possible numbers exist in which the number 2 appears exactly
>   twice?

I did:
$$(1\cdot1\cdot9\cdot9\cdot9) \cdot 5 \cdot2 = 7290$$
Which my book says is correct.

However, I want to solve this problem using probability. I tried $$\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac{9}{10} = \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^3$$
$$\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^3 \cdot (10^5-1) = 72899.271$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At most twice or exactly twice?

Comment: @barakmanos Exactly twice.

Comment: You can write $5\cdot3$ or $5\times3$; you don't need to write $5*3$.  An asterisk used for that purpose is a workaround for occasions when you are limited to the characters on the keyboard. When you're a guest at a state dinner in Buckingham palace you don't eat mashed potatoes by shoving your face into the plate. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In calculating the probability, you have accounted for only one ordering, namely $(2,2,a,b,c)$, where $a,b,c$ are any digit but $2$. You must also account for $(2,a,2,b,c), (2,a,b,2,c)$, etc.

There are ${5 \choose 2} = 10$ ways to determine the positions of the $2$s in the ticket. This is why your first answer was correct, although it's not clear why you wrote $5 \cdot 2$ instead of $5 \choose 2$. (They both come out to $10$, but what was your reasoning?)

The probability of choosing a winning ticket at random is
$$\frac{7290}{10^5-1} \approx 0.07290.$$

Comment: I did 5*2 because if you imagine each position as a slot, you have 5 slots where each 2 can be put in. Then, because you have 2 twos and they don't have to be together, you multiply that by 2. If the twos  had to be together, you'd multiply only by 5. I don't think $5 \choose 2$ is the best option, because the order matters in this case. I think. What do you think?

Comment: There are $5$ ways to choose the first slot for a $2$. Once that is taken, there are $4$ choices for the second $2$. This makes a total of $5\cdot4 = 20$ so far. But the $2$s are interchangeable, so we have counted all the arrangements twice. To account for this, we divide by $2$ to get $10$. This is precisely the meaning behind
$${5 \choose 2} = \frac{5\cdot4}{2} = 10.$$

Comment: So it is a coincidence that you also got $10$, because your reasoning doesn't work:
(i) If you say there are $5$ choices for the first $2$ *and* the second $2$, then you're counting arrangements where both $2$s are put in the same slot, which doesn't make sense.
(ii) Even if we allow them to be in the same slot, the number of possibilities would be $5^2$, not $5\cdot 2$.
(iii) Finally, because the $2$s are interchangeable, you should be dividing, not multiplying, by $2$.

To understand the calculation, it might help to consider the same problem but with a different number of slots.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized what I did wrong:

- First I didn't multiply $(\frac{9}{10})^3$ by the $\frac{1}{10}$, I don't know why:

$$\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac{9}{10} = \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^3\cdot(\frac{1}{10})^2 = .00729$$

- Then I have to multiply it by 10 (because there's $5 \choose 2 $ or $5 \cdot 2$ possibilities for places where the number 2 is in the ticket)

$$.00729 \cdot 10 = .0729$$

$$.0729 \cdot (10^5-1) \approx 7290 $$